# Use of deprecated module md5

Tags: md5, hashlib

I am using the following code in python:

```
from hashlib import md5
user_code = string.upper( md5.new(user_str).hexdigest() )
```

and the warning is

DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead

Could you please help how to update this code so that is runs also on the current version of python?

Thanks!

Comment: the only way you'd be seeing that warning would be if you are using the old md5 module rather than the md5 constructor from the hashlib module.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify which version of python you're using. I'll assume you're using 2.7 not 3

```
import hashlib

user_str = "foo"    
user_code = hashlib.md5(user_str).hexdigest().upper()
```

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib

Comment: Thanks. The second and final question is now how to resolve the following warning: